# Lua Telnet Send & Receive

Tags: sockets, lua, telnet, game-development

I'm trying to get a simple telnet session working in Lua. I've looked around the internet and haven't found a solution to my problem, which is trying to send data as well as receive it.

So far I've got this script, which receives data, but I cannot send anything in return:

```
local socket = require "socket"
local ip, port = "avalon-rpg.com", 23
local server, err = socket.connect(ip, port)

if server == nil then
  print(err)
else
  while true do
    s, status, partial = server:receive()
    print(s or partial)
    if status == "closed" then
      break
    end
  end
end

server:close()
```

Could someone please tell me what I must add to this so it will receive input and send it to the server as well? Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to *either* send *or* receive, because you cannot do both at any one time. Using `socket:setTimeout`, you can at least make the **receiving** part non-blocking. However, file IO in Lua is always blocking, so you will have to either

a) use an external library to read from stdin without blocking the program flow

b) restrict functionality of your program

As for b), you can define that your client will always wait for a response after having sent a command (so additionally sent text from the server will **not** be visible until you issue a new command). As I guess that you want to connect to a [MUD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUD), this is probably a reasonable thing to do (although I do not know the specific MUD that you are trying to connect to).

Once you have figured out what to do (use an external library or wait for user input indefinitely), you can relatively simply send your commands:

```
while true do
    local s, status, partial = server:receive()
    print(s or partial)
    if status == "closed" then
        break
    end

    -- Read from stdin
    local input = io.read("*l")
    if input ~= "" then
        server:send(input)
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Henrik. Is option A the safer option? How would I go about doing that? I tested out your code snippet there, but it's not what I wanted. I just wanted it to have the same functionality as a `telnet avalon-rpg.com` would have.

Comment: Option A is obviously the better option, as it allows the user to use your application in the way they are used to. Unfortunately, there seems to be no platform-independent way of doing this. It seems like you could use [LuaLanes](https://github.com/LuaLanes/lanes) to achieve multi-threading, but I have never used it and cannot say anything about it. If you are on windows, you can use [winapi](http://stevedonovan.github.io/winapi/api.html#get_console), on unix you can use [this function](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2014-03/msg00501.html)