# Using Lua to send telnet commands?

Tags: lua, telnet

So here's my situation, I want to control a software using a touchscreen, the software needs to receive commands via telnet. Looking around I found a software named TouchOSC made to control musical instruments by creating your own interface, this app can also run lua scripts when a button is pressed and this is where my question comes from : Can I have a Lua script that sends a telnet command when ran and also receive a state back.

I'm a total beginner in coding in general I just know the basics.
(I'm also french so sorry for the poor english)
Thanks for the help !

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lua Telnet Send & Receive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32085919/lua-telnet-send-receive)

Comment: That's the problem, I don't really understand the post you sent, I already tried to read it